# Traefik's routing rule when using regex

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, traefik

Using Traefik version 1.7.12 deployed to Azure Service Fabric.

I'd like Traefik to add cache-control header to the responses of certain requests from a web app which is also deployed to the cluster. The way I found this can be done is to create 2 separate services with different frontend routing rules for my application. The final result would be something like this:

```
Route Rule
Host:devmachine.localhost;PathPrefix:/
```

which adds "cache-control:no-cache" response header.

AND

```
Route Rule
Host:devmachine.localhost;Path:/{url:(.*)(/banner$|\.(js|css)\??)}
```

which adds "cache-control:max-age:86400" response header.

Here is a snippet from each service's manifest in the cluster respectively:

```
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Name="Traefik">
          <Labels xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/03/fabact-no-schema">
            <Label Key="traefik.enable">true</Label>
            <Label Key="traefik.frontend.passHostHeader">true</Label>
            <Label Key="traefik.frontend.rule">Host:devmachine.localhost;PathPrefix:/</Label>
            <Label Key="traefik.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness">true</Label>
            <Label Key="traefik.backend.healthcheck.path">/somepage</Label>
            <Label Key="traefik.backend.healthcheck.interval">60s</Label>
            <label key="traefik.frontend.headers.customResponseHeaders">cache-control:no-cache</label>
          </Labels>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>
```

AND

```
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Name="Traefik">
          <Labels xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/03/fabact-no-schema">
            <Label Key="traefik.enable">true</Label>
            <Label Key="traefik.frontend.passHostHeader">true</Label>
            <Label Key="traefik.frontend.rule">Host:devmachine.localhost;Path:/{url:(.*)(/banner$|\\.(js|css)\\??)}</Label>
            <label key="traefik.frontend.headers.customResponseHeaders">cache-control:max-age=86400</label>
            <label key="traefik.frontend.priority">200</label>
          </Labels>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>
```

Problem is that all my responses are getting "no-cache" header, as if the 2nd matcher isn't applied, including the following sample URIs (which are supposed to be handled by the 2nd routing rule):

```
https://example.com/banner
https://example.com/scripts/some.js
https://example.com/scripts/some-hdbxy778.js
https://example.com/scripts/someother.js?v=2.744
```

This is despite the fact that the 2nd routing rule is longer (since traefik is supposed to sort them by length descendingly) and the manual setting of priority (200).

Comment: Logged this with Treafik team in relation to this: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/5145

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a casing issue. Service Fabric provider in traefik deserializes extension configurations into a local type utilizing "xml.Unmarshal".

According to the docs (https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal)

> Unmarshal uses a case-sensitive comparison to match XML element names
>   to tag values and struct field names.

Which makes sense.

Traefik's documentation was updated to point this out: https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/5160